# HTML Page don't show google map

Tags: html, google-maps, google-api

I have a simple HTML page and I want to display a google map using API Access. I use this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><!-- HTML5 -->
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=blablabla&sensor=true">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644), zoom: 8};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
          }
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure that the script block is processed, but the page don't show the map.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//In the head section place these styles

```
<head>
<style>
  html{
    height:100%;
   }
   body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%;
   }
</style>
</head>
```

//In the body of your document, define the style of the map_canvas as such:

```
<body>
 <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%;"></div>

</body>
```

//right click you document and select insepct element. select the console tab in developers //tools. If no error is shown in there, then this might fix your problem 
//Best of luck 8-)

Comment: The problem was the style! Thanks. But now don't show the sensor :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First include Jquery library in your  section (before google js file)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```